# Triangle inequality and squeeze theorem question

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

firstly thank you for taking the time to help me. I have looked all over the internet for help for this answer but cannot crack it.

I have been asked to show the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A smaller denominator in magnitude means a larger number in magnitude, given that the numerator of the fraction stays the same.

$$|\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}| \leq |\frac{x^3}{x^2}|=|x|$$

$$|\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2}| \leq |\frac{y^3}{y^2}|=|y|$$

Adding both results gives,

$$|\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2}|+|\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}| \leq |x|+|y|$$

By triangle inequality (which tells us $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$) we have,

$$|\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}| \leq |\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2}|+|\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}| \leq |x|+|y|$$

To be precise. That's assuming $x \neq 0$ or $y \neq 0$. If $x=0$ and $y \neq 0$ the equality becomes trivially evident. And if $y=0$ and $x \neq 0$ the equality again becomes trivially evident.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
\begin{align}
|x|^3+|y|^3 \leq (|x|+|y|)(|x|^2+|y|^2). 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|x^2+y^2| = |x^2| + |y^2| = |x|^2 + |y|^2$. Also, by the triangle inequality $|x^3+y^3| \le |x|^3 + |y|^3 = (|x| + |y|)(|x|^2 + |y|^2 - |x||y|)$.

Therefore,

$$\left | \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}  \right | \le  \frac{|x|^3+|y|^3}{|x|^2+|y|^2} = \frac{(|x| + |y|)(|x|^2 + |y|^2 - |x||y|)}{|x|^2 + |y|^2}$$ $$ = (|x| + |y|)\left(1 - \frac{|xy|}{|x|^2+|y|^2} \right) \leq |x| + |y|$$